redirecting excessive requests from one IP to server to output of a program possible?
I have a server with apache 2.4 setup and I'm trying to limit requests while giving a simple response to google (and anyone else that exceeds rate limits).
Someone has suggested using mod_evasive with apache but that wouldn't cover all the ports I want to rate-limit.
I looked at a guide here for rate-limiting: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/iptables-packet-rate-limit
and their solution is to simply drop packets that exceed rate limits. Not good for the client here. Using REJECT instead of drop is ok but it doesn't help when someone requests webpages (on port 80/443).
Is there a way through IP tables where if a request is exceeded I can output a raw error with the HTTP header? I'm thinking something like this (which probably wont work as-is):
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 120 --hitcount 10 -j SHOW_ERROR:"HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests\r\n\r\nError"

At least if something like that can be done, apache wouldn't have to be called up again just to output a static error message.
Any ideas what I can do without putting a burden on the server?

iptables can't generate high-level protocol responses, but instead of your ficticious SHOW_ERROR target, you could redirect the connection to a secondary web server that serves only static
